Background-color not changing in sequence
In response to a button click I have the following jQuery code in a code snippet on a WP site
jQuery("#cf_course_planner tr").css("background-color", "#f66");
jQuery("#cf_course_planner tr:eq(0)").css("background-color", "#fff");
if (confirm("Confirm deletions of all entries\nEither OK or Cancel.") ==  true){
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  } else {
  return false;
  }

But when it is executed the background colour doesn't change until after the OK button is pressed on the alert command.
How do I get the background-color to change before the confirm request?
I tried introducing a console.log command writing rubbish to the console just to do something but that doesn't work.

This issue is because this is the way JS handles synchronous execution of code. When you use confirm() in JavaScript, it halts the execution of further JavaScript until the user interacts with the dialog (presses OK or Cancel). This behavior causes your background color change to appear delayed.
You can use a timeout to achieve the desired functionality.
Modified code:
jQuery("#cf_course_planner tr").css("background-color", "#f66");
jQuery("#cf_course_planner tr:eq(0)").css("background-color", "#fff");

setTimeout(function() {
  // Show confirmation dialog
  if (confirm("Confirm deletions of all entries\nEither OK or Cancel.")) {
    alert("You pressed OK!");

  } else {
    return false
  }
}, 100); // Delay time in milliseconds

